# Laravel - Complicated Timezone Issues

Tags: laravel, date, datetime, timezone

There's a few questions on this already but I can't find a good elegant way of doing this

Database is stored as UTC

I store the user's timezone in Database (column name is timezone)

**The issue is:**

When echoing out data, it's formatted as UTC. So I made a cast to convert to their timezone (like PST)

But, when storing to database, I also made another cast for setting/storing where it converts their timezone to UTC (so if they fill in a form, it's assumed to be their timezone, so we convert and store to UTC)

**This has worked for the most part, but I'm getting over 500 query calls to the database somehow**. If I remove the set cast, it drops to 40 calls, so somehow it's calling too many times. This is also odd because the set method should only be called when saving to the database, but it's being called even when it's just a view file

Here's my model:

```
protected $casts = [
        'expected' => DatetimeWithTimezone::class,
        'born' => DatetimeWithTimezone::class,
        'ready_for_homes' => DatetimeWithTimezone::class,
    ];
```

Here's my cast:

```
namespace App\Casts;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\CastsAttributes;

class DatetimeWithTimezone implements CastsAttributes
{
    /**
     * Cast the given value.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function get($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {

        if(!is_null($value)) {
            $timezone = auth()->user() ? company('timezone') : get_guest_timezone();
            $value = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value, 'UTC');
            $value->setTimezone($timezone);
        }

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the given value for storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function set($model, string $key, $value, array $attributes)
    {
        if(is_null($value)) {
            return $value;
        }

        $timezone = auth()->user() ? company('timezone') : get_guest_timezone();

        $convertedDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value, $timezone);

        $convertedDate->setTimezone('UTC');

        return $convertedDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: do both function company('timezone') and get_guest_timezone() collect data from database query? perhaps you can reduce your query by moving company() into auth()->user()->timezone, and get guest using config('guest.timezone')

Comment: @Win yes they both get from the database "timezone" column. I'll attempt that, thanks!